# How to join dataframes conditionally on column pairs?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two df

```
d1 <- data_frame(name=c('Mike','Carl','Joe', 'Mike'), 
           id=c(1,2,NA,1), 
           id2=c('a',NA,'c','a'),
           dateT=as.Date('2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2016-05-01'))


   # A tibble: 4 x 4
   name    id   id2      dateT
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <date>
1  Mike     1     a 2017-05-01
2  Carl     2  <NA> 2017-05-01
3   Joe    NA     c 2017-05-01
4  Mike     1     a 2016-05-01

d2 <- data_frame(value=c(T, T, F, T,F), 
                 id=c(1,2,3,1,4), 
                 id2=c('a','b','c','a','d'),
                 dateT=as.Date('2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2017-05-01', '2016-05-01','2016-05-01'))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  value    id   id2      dateT
  <lgl> <dbl> <chr>     <date>
1  TRUE     1     a 2017-05-01
2  TRUE     2     b 2017-05-01
3 FALSE     3     c 2017-05-01
4  TRUE     1     a 2016-05-01
5 FALSE     4     d 2016-05-01
```

And I am trying to join `d2` with `d1` based the pairs `dateT` and `id` *or* `date` and `id2` depending on which one is available.
Eventually, I would like to have all the records from d2 (wether they matched or not), and attached all the columns from d1 which have a match on d2.

What I have so far is

```
d2 %>% 
  inner_join(d1, by=c('id'='id', 'dateT'='dateT'))



 # A tibble: 5 x 6
  value    id id2.x      dateT  name id2.y
  <lgl> <dbl> <chr>     <date> <chr> <chr>
1  TRUE     1     a 2017-05-01  Mike     a
2  TRUE     2     b 2017-05-01  Carl  <NA>
3 FALSE     3     c 2017-05-01  <NA>  <NA>
4  TRUE     1     a 2016-05-01  Mike     a
5 FALSE     4     d 2016-05-01  <NA>  <NA>
```

There are two issues:

1. I would rather attach only `name` from `d1`, since in my case `id2.y` is always gonna be a subset of `id2.x` (I want to keep only `id2.x` because it is always gonna be most complete). I know I can drop the columns later on, but I was wondering if dplyr has any functionality that would keep only the columns from the first dataframe in presence of duplicated column names
2. I don't know how to conditionally look in `id2` when `is.na(id)==T`

The expected output would look like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  value    id   id2      dateT  name 
  <lgl> <dbl> <chr>     <date> <chr> 
1  TRUE     1     a 2017-05-01  Mike 
2  TRUE     2     b 2017-05-01  Carl 
3 FALSE     3     c 2017-05-01   Joe 
4  TRUE     1     a 2016-05-01  Mike 
5 FALSE     4     d 2016-05-01  <NA>
```

Comment: Can you please post your expected output?

Comment: @Sotos output added, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
# first join by id, dropping id2
join1 = select(d1, -id2) %>%
    inner_join(d2, ., by=c("dateT", "id"))
# now take what couldn't be joined with id,
# drop id, join by id2, + left join to keep the remainder
join2 = d2 %>%
    anti_join(d1, by=c("dateT", "id")) %>%
    left_join(select(d1, -id), by=c("dateT", "id2"))

bind_rows(join1, join2)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  value    id   id2      dateT  name
  <lgl> <dbl> <chr>     <date> <chr>
1  TRUE     1     a 2017-05-01  Mike
2  TRUE     2     b 2017-05-01  Carl
3  TRUE     1     a 2016-05-01  Mike
4 FALSE     4     d 2016-05-01  <NA>
5 FALSE     3     c 2017-05-01   Joe
```

Note that this code attempts to use `id2` whenever `id` join fails, not only when `id` is `NA`.
Frankly, my approach requires three joins, so on a huge dataset it could be faster to recode the `id` variable - but that's difficult to do without knowing what it means in your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

d1 <- data_frame(name=c('Mike','Carl','Joe', 'Mike'), 
                 id=c(1,2,NA,1), 
                 id2=c('a',NA,'c','a'),
                 dateT=as.Date(c('2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2016-05-01')))
# add combine-"c" !!

d2 <- data_frame(value=c(T, T, F, T,F), 
                 id=c(1,2,3,1,4), 
                 id2=c('a','b','c','a','d'),
                 dateT=as.Date(c('2017-05-01','2017-05-01','2017-05-01', '2016-05-01','2016-05-01')))
# add combine-"c" !!

left_join(d2,
          d1 %>%
            select(name, id, dateT) %>%
            rename(name1=name),
          by=c("id", "dateT")) %>%
  left_join(d1 %>%
              select(name, id2, dateT) %>%
              rename(name2=name),
            by=c("id2", "dateT")) %>%
  transmute(value, id, id2, dateT, 
            name=ifelse(is.na(name1),name2,name1))
```

Comment: Thanks, the output looks good, but I find hard to generalize your approach to larger datasets. The issue is that it is not truly conditional on the value of id/id2